# Movie about a very unlucky guy that discovers magic

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie takes place in some alternate universe where "luck" is scientifically proved to exist. Furthermore, every child (I think) needs to take a test that checks their luck. The two main protagonists take the exam at the start of the movie, and it is discovered that the girl protagonist has an enormous amount of luck, while the guy protagonist almost has negative luck (I think).

Then later in the movie we get a timeskip, and the guy protagonist discovers magic somehow which allows him to up his luck (?) and starts dating the woman protagonist. In the end, it is discovered that the magic manipulated her feelings and she leaves him.

The movie is a live action American (I believe, but might be from some other English-speaking country) movie, which I watched 7~10 years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be thinking of the independent British film, *[Frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequencies_(film))* (2013).

At the beginning of the film, we see a group of school kids take some sort of written exam, wearing blindfolds. After the exam, a blonde girl, named Marie, reveals that she scored 127, and a nearby boy remarks that the scores don't go higher than 100. Another boy, named Zak, is revealed to have scored -7.

The movie follows these two characters as they age into young adulthood, at which point they become romantically involved. There's no actual magic in the story, but Zak discovers that he can temporarily increase his own luck using certain sounds articulated as made-up words.

An excerpt from the Wikipedia plot summary:

> The plot develops in a world where every person emits a specific frequency which determines his or her luck, further determining his or her success in life. Higher frequency means better luck and thus less feelings.
>
> In this world where relationship, connections, and life worth is determined by predestined "frequencies", Isaac-Newton Midgeley, known as Zak, is a Low Born who wants to change his fate and start a relationship with High Born savant, Marie-Curie Fortune.

Comment: Yess, this is the movie! Thank you very much!